# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2019

One of our projects has to be moved from Oracle to SQL server. I converted one of the queries from Oracle to SQL Server and I am receiving the error below now (the query works in Oracle).

It is complaining about every column that has SUM in it. Would anyone know how to correct it, how to modify the query so it work also in SQL Server?

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Here is the converted query for SQL Server that is having the issues with all columns that contain `SUM`:

```
SELECT  
    epoch, sourceID,  
    SUM(CASE (SELECT classification 
              FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl 
              WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID)  
            WHEN 'Class_A' THEN Estimate  
            ELSE 0 
         END) "Class_A" ,
    SUM(CASE ISNULL((SELECT classification 
                     FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl 
                     WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID), 'InvalidCls')  
            WHEN 'NonValid' THEN Estimate ELSE 0 
         END) "NonValid" ,
    SUM(CASE (SELECT classification 
              FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl 
              WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID)  
           WHEN 'Class_A' 
               THEN 0 
               ELSE (CASE ISNULL((SELECT classification 
                                  FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl 
                                  WHERE cl.Classification_Id = tr.TimeWorkTypeID), 'InvalidCls')
                          WHEN 'NonValid' 
                              THEN 0  
                          WHEN 'InvalidCls' 
                              THEN Estimate  
                          ELSE Estimate 
                      END)  
        END) "Authorized" ,     
    SUM(CASE (SELECT classification 
              FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl 
              WHERE cl.Classification_Id = tr.TimeWorkTypeID) 
           WHEN 'General' THEN Estimate ELSE 0  
        END) "General" 
FROM 
    TimeReports TR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Proposals p ON tr.TimeWorkTypeID = p.ProposalCode
WHERE 
    Accepted = 'Y'
    AND tr.epoch BETWEEN 100 AND 300
GROUP BY 
    tr.epoch, tr.sourceID;
```

Here is the original Oracle query for reference:

```
SELECT  
    epoch, sourceID,  
    SUM(DECODE( (SELECT classification FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID), 'Class_A',   Estimate, 0) )          "Class_A" ,
    SUM(DECODE ( NVL((SELECT classification FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID),'InvalidCls' ), 'NonValid', Estimate, 0) )          "NonValid" ,
    SUM(DECODE ( (SELECT classification FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl WHERE cl.Classification_Id = p.Proposal_ID), 'Class_A', 0, 
                (DECODE( NVL((SELECT classification FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl WHERE cl.Classification_Id = tr.TimeWorkTypeID),'InvalidCls'),
                'NonValid', 0,  
                'InvalidCls', Estimate, Estimate) ) )   )           "Authorized" ,     
     SUM(DECODE ( (SELECT classification FROM CLASSIFICATION_lookup cl WHERE cl.Classification_Id = tr.TimeWorkTypeID),'General', Estimate, 0 ) )                "General" 
FROM 
    TimeReports TR, Proposals p
WHERE Accepted = 'Y'
AND tr.epoch between 100 AND 300
AND tr.TimeWorkTypeID = p.ProposalCode(+)
GROUP BY tr.epoch, tr.sourceID;
```

I tried removing columns containing SUM and the query works, of course (but we need those columns).

I am not sure what the best approach would be, I was thinking if converting those subqueries into functions would work, but I am afraid that it would be huge performance hit since the query returns several millions records (it is part of scheduled job to copy data).

The SQL Server is running version 2019 if it makes a difference.

I appreciate any help, tips, ideas etc.!

Comment: Could you help with the table structure with basic data? @Joed

Comment: Try to use ``TOP 1`` on your subqueries